# I need to generate two letters to a person (one for each address). How can I accomplish this?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008

I would like to create two letters for a single person.  One letter will be sent to a person's old address and another will be sent to a person's new address.  Would this be two different reports with a slight variation in the SQL or is there a way to simply create both letters with a single report?

Comment: If the only thing that is different is the address, then one report will do the trick. Just have field(s) in the report for the address and let it populate at runtime. Are the two addresses in different records, or in different fields in the same record?

Comment: Please provide some more info. Database (Tables, etc.) strucutre.

Comment: Currently, both addresses are in a single record in separate fields.  One is called `OldAddress` and the other is `NewAddress`.

Comment: I don't understand though what I should do.  Maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way.  I've never done a letter before in SSRS.  As of right now, I'm simply showing a textbox that has their address.  However, I'm not sure how I can set it for both fields but have only one display.  Only thing I can think of would be to use an If statement that says "If the page is odd, send to old address.  If page is even send to new."  As long as each letter is one page, this should work correct?  Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a normallized database, you would show the old address and new address in two separate records, perhaps in a related table linked by person ID or something similar. You should look up and read about normalization. Certainly you should aim for at least 3rd normal form.

For your current problem, you could create a unionized view

```
select NewAddress As Address from TableName
union
select OldAddress as Address from TableName
```

Then report on the values in the view.
You might want to have some more fields as well, such as the person's name.
The fields you select in the first select statement must be the same number and type as those in the second select statement.
Also you can still add a where clause and an order by clause.

Check on the union operator online.

Hope this helps

Harv

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches you could use:

- union the old and new addresses in the query, then report on the query with a single detail section for each dataset row.
- alternatively, report off the Table and include **two** detail rows, one each for the old and new address, and conditionally suppress each section depending on whether the relevant address is NULL.